# Force NHibernate to accept identity generator for union-subclass

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I have a table X, which primary key "ID" is an identity int column.

This table is mapped to two classes (once directly and then through a synonym), X and ExtendedX (which extend X).

ExtendedX just adds a few IList, IDictionnary (one-to-many) properties, that's why it doesn't  need any specific new column in addition to what X already has.
So I made ExtendedX map to a synonim of X (to work arround NHibernate "table already mapped" limitation) as a "concrete subclass" (<union-subclass...>)

The issue there, is a safeguard NHibernate has regarding the usage of Identity column for union-sublass (I know it looks like an error when you don't know both mapped tables are actually one and the same), it prevents this configuration by default.

How can I have NHibernate not refuse to use the identity generator for my concrete table per subclass mapping?

Answer (score 1):

`union-subclass` feature requires the key of union-ed table to be assignable on inserts. And another roadblock would happens on inserts if you trick it by using a duplicated non identity id column: on insert, NHibernate would issue two inserts on your table for one entity, one insert for the base class and another one for the union-ed subclass.

So you may then need to trick even a bit more by having all base columns nullable except the identity, add a trigger for detecting the second insert (would have the dup id set) and use the dup id to locate the base record and update it accordingly (setting its duplicated id column to the identity value by the way), then cancel the second insert... Pew, it starts to be a great coding horror.